# Map entries of StructuredArray

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I have the following defintion

```
arr = SymmetrizedArray[{1, 2} -> 1, {4, 4}, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]
```

which gives a `StructuredArray` with one entry `{1,2}->1`. I would like to map this array to a new one on a (key,value) basis, i.e. the desired result would look like something like this:

```
desiredResult = SymmetrizedArray[f[{1, 2}] -> g[1], {4, 4}, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]
```

How do I go about this without converting to a normal matrix?

I found out that for `SparseArray` one can do

```
SparseArray[{{1, 2} -> 1, {2, 1} -> -1}, {4, 4}]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

to get all available keys, but I actually would like to not convert my `StructuredArray` to a `SparseArray` to keep the number of entries at a minimum. Unfortunately an analogous syntax doesn't work with `SparseArray`.

Thanks a lot!